# How to write tests based on django's Settings Module

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tox

I have a project where I need to add certain third-party application access keys into settings module, say AWS keys. How do I write tests for them? something like below?

```
def test_it_can_read_aws_keys(self):
   assert settings.KEY_1 is None
   assert settings.KEY_2 is None
   # now somehow i need to add/simulate the keys in settings.py like below
   # KEY_1 = 'xxx'
   # KEY_2 = 'yyy'
   assert settings.KEY_1 is 'xxx'
   assert settings.KEY_2 is 'yyy'
```

Comment: Well Django settings are *immutable*, so it would be strange to do that. Furthermore here you would test if Djang's `settings` module works correctly, which you usually can assume will work (well if not, the problem is usually not something that you should solve). So I do not really understand what you aim to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You can import que settings 'from django.conf import settings' and teste the values. But be carefull, try test the comportament not the existence of variable.